# What values can $\int \frac{1}{\omega(\omega^2 - 1)}$ take on a circle

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm wondering what values the following integral can take when evaluated on a circle $C$? How would I compute the entire set of values that this integral can take on a circle?

$$\int_C \frac{1}{\omega(\omega^2 - 1)} d\omega$$

Note that we know that $-1,0,1$ are all not on the circle over which we are integrating.

Thanks,
Helen

Comment: Have you learned about residues?

Comment: Nothing in-depth unfortunately. I would have thought that Cauchy's Theorem for a Star-Shaped Region would apply here and tell us that the integral is 0 but that can't be correct.

Comment: Well, $\mathbb C\setminus\{-1,0,1\}$ is not star-shaped, so that shouldn't be a surprise. Residues are what you need here -- even shallow knowledge should be useful.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I was getting confused and just thinking that the "star shaped region" was referring to the interior of the circle. Of course, that makes much more sense. What approach would I use here? I have broken the integral into three integrals (partial fractions).

Comment: Would I consider different cases ie. 0,-1,1 outside C, 0 inside C and the others outside C etc? In certain cases, the star-shaped region theorem would apply? I'm not sure what I would do for example in the case where -1 is inside C and the others are outside... two of the integrals would be 0, right? But what about the other integral?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a circle $C$ that does not go through $-1,0$ or $1$,
$$\oint_C \frac{dz}{z(z^2-1)} = 2\pi i\cdot \sum_{\zeta\in Z}\text{Res}\left(\frac{1}{z(z^2-1)},z=\zeta\right)\tag{1}$$
where $Z$ is the set of points among $\{-1,0,1\}$ that are enclosed by $C$. Since:
$$ \frac{1}{z(z-1)(z+1)} = \frac{-1}{z}+\frac{\frac{1}{2}}{z-1}+\frac{\frac{1}{2}}{z+1} \tag{2}$$
the possible values for the LHS of $(1)$ are $-2\pi i,-\pi i,0,\pi i$. $2\pi i$ is not a possible value since every circle enclosing $-1$ and $1$ encloses $0$, too.

Comment: I'm sure this is correct but I don't have the residue theorem at my disposal unfortunately. Nonetheless, to have the correct answers to verify with is very useful, so, thanks for your help!